# Is there a more succinct way to say "decided instead to..."?

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for better ways to say "decided instead to..."

I've only thought so far of synonyms for each word, "elected instead to...," "decided rather..." etc.; however, I'm looking for something a bit more brief.

Comment: "He wanted to go to the park ***but decided*** to go to the gym."

Comment: Why do you think "decided instead to" is not succinct. Why do you need a more succinct word? What is the full sentence? What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

As Nate said, there's an artistic element in our choice of phrasing. Your original phrase describes the person's thought processes. We can be more succinct:

```
He decided to go to the gym rather than the park.

He chose the gym instead of the park.
```

but the effect is not quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

If it's brevity that your after, "He **decided** to go home" is a complete statement.  Unless introducing more than one option, there's no need to add "instead of", "rather than" or "as opposed to". Nevertheless, a more succinct form of comparison is possible using a transitive verb: "He **chose** brevity over clarity" for instance.

One final note: "decided instead to go" would be better phrased as "decided to go instead".  While punctuation is less common nowadays, your phrasing would technically require commas, as in "I decided, instead, to go home."